# R dplyr: change the row value of columns having an specific name

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame. One of the columns has string values that I want to use as a condition for the name of the other columns. For example,

```
df <- data.frame(
  cond=c("a","b"),
  aVal=c(1  , 2),
  bVal=c(3  , 4)
)
```

I want to check the name of each column in the df row by row, if the colname does not start with cond then I want to set the value of that column to 0.
The expected output here will be.

```
#    cond aVal bVal
# 1    a    1    0
# 2    b    0    4
```

I am not sure how to do this with R preferably with dplyr.

Comment: start with row 1. get the cond which is "a" then select all the columns for that row that their names do not start with "a" and set their values to 0. continue this for every row. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution. Notice that I used `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to create your example data frame for avoiding factor columns. `df2` is the final output.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>%
  gather(Column, Value, -cond) %>%
  mutate(Column2 = str_sub(Column, 1, 1)) %>%
  mutate(Value = ifelse(map2_lgl(cond, Column2, ~str_detect(.y, .x)), Value, 0)) %>%
  select(-Column2) %>%
  spread(Column, Value)
df2
#   cond aVal bVal
# 1    a    1    0
# 2    b    0    4
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(
  cond=c("a","b"),
  aVal=c(1  , 2),
  bVal=c(3  , 4),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Comment: The solution should not depend on Val to be scalable.

Comment: I have updated my answer. It was not clear to me if "Val" is consistent for all columns. Next time, you should include this kind of important information.

Comment: More on that, there is no information to guarantee the character length in the `cond` column and the column names is always a length one letter, so removing "Val" seems to be a safe option to me.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a `base R` option

```
df[-1] <- df[-1] * t(apply(df, 1, function(x)  substr(names(x)[-1], 1, 1) == x[1]))
df
#   cond aVal bVal
#1    a    1    0
#2    b    0    4
```

Also a variation of the above would be

```
df[-1] * (substr(matrix(names(df)[-1][row(df[-1])], 2, 2), 1, 1) == 
               df$cond[col(df[-1])])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(
  cond=c("a","b"),
  aVal=c(1  , 2),
  bVal=c(3  , 4)
)

gather(df, col1, col2, -cond) %>% 
  as.tibble() %>% 
  filter(str_sub(col1, 1, 1) == cond) %>% 
  spread(col1, col2) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(contains('Val')),
            funs(replace(., is.na(.), 0)))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  cond   aVal  bVal
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         1     0
2 b         0     4
```

Comment: The solution should not depend on Val to be scalable.